# Having problem to render home page after authenticating user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I am using express and mongo DB as back end languages and the module passport to authenticate user but after the user authenticates, it returns a error message saying 'Bad Request' and the home page is never rendered. I have tried my

```js
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.render('login');
});

app.get('/login',(req,res) => {
  res.render('login');
});

app.get('/signup',(req,res) => {
  res.render('signup');
})

app.get("/logout", function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/");
});


app.get("/home",(req,res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render('home');
  }else{
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});



app.post("/login", function(req, res){

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/home");
      });
    }
  });
});






app.post('/signup',(req,res) => {
  User.register({name:req.body.name,username:req.body.email},req.body.password,(err,user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/signup');
    }else{
      passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,() => {
        res.redirect('/home');
      })
    }
  })
});
```

to solve the error but I am unable to. Please someone help for this case

Comment: Please provider the error message that comes along with the "bad request". (Browser Dev Tools Console, the console where you started the node server).

Comment: no error message just it says 'Bad Request' over the browser and doesn't log any kind of error that's why I cannot figure out the issue

Comment: Start by running the server in debug mode. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

Comment: i have done that and i got this message :-    express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUniniti
alized option server.js:28:9